Mapping elements of a structure to different vector elements using reflection (compile-time)
I recently have hit a wall, and can't seem to find an elegant solution to my problem:
I have different data structures of different number of elements, all of which are aligned to pointer-size and are not larger than a pointer, ex.:
struct DATA_0{
    size_t      Value;
    size_t      *PtrValue;
    bool        BoolValue;
};

or
struct DATA_1{
    size_t      Value0;
    size_t      Value1;
    size_t      *PtrValue;
    void        *PtrBuffer;
    bool        BoolValue;
    const char  *StringBuffer;
}

The input comes in a form like this:
struct INPUT{
    size_t *DataBuffer;
    size_t DataVector[16];
};

I need to map the data structures to different elements from either the DataBuffer or the DataVector, at compile time:

the mapping rule is being controlled by #defines/compile time switches - for a given compilation configuration, the mapping rule is the same for all structures.
a given data structure member can be mapped to either a DataBuffer or a DataVector
a data structure member's index (no need for offset, since the data is aligned) defines the element it is mapped to, ex.: in some cases the element at index 0 (DATA_0::Value or DATA_1::Value0 for example) maps to DataVector[3], and in other cases to DataBuffer[0]
for those elements, that have no index based mapping rules (usually the first 2-4 elements from a structure have such rule), they all should map to sequential elements, onward from a given element from DataBuffer

Some example of desired usage:
INPUT_DATA *input;

data_mapping<DATA_0> mapping_0(input);
//will fetch data from input->DataVector[0] in some cases, input->DataBuffer[0] in other
size_t tmpValue = mapping_0[Value];

data_mapping<DATA_1> mapping_1(input);
//will fetch data from input->DataVector[1] in some cases, input->DataBuffer[3] in other
size_t tmpPtrBuffer = mapping_1[PtrBuffer];

NOTE: the data does not need to be necessarily represented by structures, it can be even variadic template argument too, ex.: <size_t, Value, size_t, PtrValue, bool, BoolValue>
Here is an pseudo-code example of what i am trying to achieve:
template<class TMember, class TData>
TMember GetElement(INPUT_DATA *Input, TData Data)
{
#ifdef FIRST_CASE
    if(indexof(TMember) == 0)
    {
        return Input->DataVector[0];
    }
    if(indexof(TMember) == 1)
    {
        return Input->DataVector[1];
    }
    return Input->DataBuffer[indexof(TMember) - 2];
#else
    if(indexof(TMember) == 0)
    {
        return Input->DataVector[2];
    }
    if(indexof(TMember) == 1)
    {
        return Input->DataVector[3];
    }
    if(indexof(TMember) == 2)
    {
        return Input->DataVector[4];
    }
    if(indexof(TMember) == 3)
    {
        return Input->DataVector[5];
    }
    return Input->DataBuffer[indexof(TMember)];
#endif
}

size_t tmpValue = GetElement<Value>(input,DATA_0);
size_t tmpPtrBuffer = GetElement<PtrBuffer>(input,DATA_1);


Value and PtrBuffer are not valid names on their own. &DATA_0::PtrBuffer and &DATA_1::PtrBuffer are, but they have different types, so you'll have a whole load of overloads of operator[] for your desired syntax.
I think the easiest thing for you to do here is just write out some functions
DATA_0 to_data_0(INPUT input) {
    DATA_0 result;
    result.Value = input.DataVector[0];
    // etc.
    return result;
}

DATA_1 to_data_1(INPUT input) {
    DATA_1 result;
    result.Value0 = input.DataVector[2];
    // etc.
    return result;
}

If you have different configurations, then you will need different versions of these functions.
